# How is sandpaper quality determined?

Tags: sanding

In chat today, Karl mentioned that there's a very large disparity in sandpaper quality. Now, I knew about grit differences (they refer to the fineness of the grain, iirc) but literal quality?

So, how is sandpaper quality determined? What makes a good quality sandpaper and what makes a low quality one? Is there a way to evaluate quality by touch/sensory perception alone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a fascinating article in Fine Homebuilding # 221, pg. 73, where they torture test various brands of sandpaper discs and find that there's a HUGE gap in performance between the stuff that you can buy at Lowe's (Gator) and the stuff you can find only at good woodworking/tool stores or online (Mirka and Klingspor). I've typically used Mirka when I can get it; I will be trying some of the Klingspor discs soon since it was rated so much more highly. They also rated 3m highly, but didn't look at things like sanding sponges or normal block sanding paper, they just looked at discs.

There's three different things that seem to go into it. First, the quality of the abrasive. Cheap abrasive (Gator) will not hold the sharp 'edges' that make sandpaper feel gritty very long. The second is if there are any additional coatings. Norton, Mirka, and Klingspor have a Stearate coating that keeps the discs from loading up with the dust and grime from the object you're sanding. As auujay mentioned, there is a difference in the paper -- most used "C" grade paper, where Klingspor uses the "F" grade paper, which is much stiffer, but that seems to be the least of the issues with the sanding discs.

I should note that I've had really bad results with the Norton "universal" 5/8 hole disc design -- it seems to leave a lot of orbiter marks.

Answer (score 3):

IMO two factors I can think of would be the strength of the backing paper (how easily does it rip and tear) and how well the "grit" sticks to that paper.  You don't want the sandpaper to rip and get a hole in it when going over sharp edges or corners.  The better the "grit" stays on the paper the longer you can use a single piece.

However, I have no idea how you would determine these qualities while at the store.